# Django CMS warnings

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using djangocms-installer and the installation process was successful created my project successfully but when i run my project it is displaying these warnings. Any ideas to resolve it?

```
/home/paul/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/placeholderadmin.py:132: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Options.module_name has been deprecated in favor of model_name
  info = "%s_%s" % (self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name)

/home/paul/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py:111: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Options.module_name has been deprecated in favor of model_name
  info = "%s_%s" % (self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name)

/home/paul/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/settingsadmin.py:25: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Options.module_name has been deprecated in favor of model_name
  info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py:37: RemovedInDjango18Warning: XViewMiddleware has been moved to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.
  __import__(name)
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. It has to do with Django CMS's support of older versions of django.

Comment: I am using django 1.7

Comment: Again, it has to do with Django CMS's **support** of older versions of Django

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning of an already deprecated feature that will be removed in the next version of django (1.8)

You can find this in the [release notes of Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#features-removed-in-1-8)

> **Features removed in 1.8**
>
> These features have reached the end of their deprecation cycle and so have been removed in Django 1.8 (please see the deprecation timeline for more details):
>
> **django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware** is removed.
>
> The **Model._meta.module_name alias** is removed.

Answer (score 0):

That may be caused by older Django version you are using.
In 1.6

> The XViewMiddleware has been moved from django.middleware.doc to
>   django.contrib.admindocs.middleware

And that's exactly what your error says.
If you use virtualenv (I'm sure you do, if not - make sure you do, that will save you a lot of work!) get more recent version of Django.

Comment: I am using django 1.7